# How can I insert a break between (multiple choice) answers in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a quiz using javascript as a fun thing for my website. I followed a tutorial using https://www.sitepoint.com/simple-javascript-quiz/ , and after a bit of trial and error got it working with one question. But, as it is a multiple choice quiz, there are different choices to click on. The choices are all on one line. How can I change the code so that they are on separate lines? To help with any misconceptions, here are the choices and the code:

. a : 28    . b : 34   . c : 33   . d : More Information needed

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<style>
#sometext {
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  color: white;
}

/* Add padding to containers */
.container {
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #9999;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar a:hover{
  background-color: red;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(150, 175, 200);
}

#p {
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2em;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #000, #fff, #000);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 80%;
  animation: animate 3s linear infinite;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

#Header {
  background-color: rgb(150, 175, 200);
  color: Black;
  font-family: Courier;
  font-size: 50px;
  background-position: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ccc,
  0 2px 0 #c9c9c9,
  0 3px 0 #bbb,
  0 4px 0 #b9b9b9,
  0 5px 0 #aaa,
  0 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
  0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
  0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3),
  0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
  0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25),
  0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
  0 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.15);

}

@keyframes animate {
   0% {
    background-position: -500%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 500%;
  }
}
</style>
<body>

  <nav class="navbar">
    <a href = "file:///C:/Users/xenia/De
    sktop/InfoSpace/Home.html">Home</a>
    <a href = "file:///C:/Users/xe
    nia/Desktop/InfoSpace/Profile.html">My Profile</a>
    <a href = "file:///C:/Users/xenia/Desktop
    /InfoSpace/Articles.html">Articles</a>
    <a href = "file:///C:/Users/xenia
    /Desktop/InfoSpace/Reviews.html">Reviews</a>
    <a href = "file:///C:/Users/xenia/Desktop
    /InfoSpace/Tutorials.html">Tutorials</a>
    <a href = "file:///C:/Users/xe
    nia/Desktop/InfoSpace/Help.html">Help</a>
  </nav>

  <h1 id="Header"><strong>INFOSPACE</strong></h1>

  <p id="sometext">
    <br />
    This site is dedicated to provide information for budding scientists. 
    We aim to give you
    a enjoyable and informative experience. If you experience a bug in 
    the
site please email Samuel Crawford at samuelhbc@icloud.com. Our blogs are reviews of products.
In each one there is a link to the product. If the link is no longer relevent please email samuelhbc@icloud.com.
Thank you for your attention and enjoy!!!
<br />
<br />
 </p>

 <br />
 <br />

 <h1><strong>IQ Test</strong></h1>
<div id = "quiz">

 </div>

 <button id = "submit"><h1>Submit Quiz</h1></button>

 <div id = "results">

 </div>

 <br />
 <br />

 <p id="p">A website for young scientists.</p>

 </body>
 <script>
 const quizContainer = document.getElementById('quiz');
 const resultsContainer = document.getElementById('results');
 const submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');

 const myQuestions = [
   {
     question: "What is the next number in this sequence: 
     1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21...",

     answers: {

     a: "28",
     b: "34",
     c: "33",
     d: "More Information needed"

     },
     correctAnswer: "b"

    },

  ];

 function buildQuiz() {

    const output = [];

    myQuestions.forEach(
      (currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {

      const answers = [];

       for(letter in currentQuestion.answers){

         answers.push(
            `<label>
            <input type="radio" name="question${questionNumber}" 
     value="${letter}">
      ${letter} :
      ${currentQuestion.answers[letter]}
      </label>`
    );
  }

  output.push(
    `<div class="question"> ${currentQuestion.question} </div>
    <div class="answers"> ${answers.join('')} </div>`
  );
}
);

  quizContainer.innerHTML = output.join('');
}

function showResults() {
  const answerContainers = quizContainer.querySelectorAll('.answers');

  let numCorrect = 0;

  myQuestions.forEach( (currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {

const answerContainer = answerContainers[questionNumber];
const selector = 'input[name=question'+questionNumber+']:checked';
const userAnswer = (answerContainer.querySelector(selector) || {}).value;

if(userAnswer===currentQuestion.correctAnswer){
  numCorrect++;

  answerContainers[questionNumber].style.color = 'lightgreen';
}

else{
  answerContainers[questionNumber].style.color = 'red';
}
});

resultsContainer.innerHTML = numCorrect + ' out of ' + 
myQuestions.length;

}

buildQuiz();

submitButton.addEventListener('click', showResults);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish this, so I'm not going to post an answer because there will be many answers as everyone will want to do it there way. But a quick and simple way is add `<br>` after `</label>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One relatively easy way to do this would be to use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox). In this case, you would add the following styles to your document:

```css
.answers {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

`display: flex` makes the `.answers` divs flex elements, and `flex-direction: column` displays the div's content from top to bottom instead of from left to right. Once you have that, you can apply other flex properties to arrange the answers even more precisely to your liking. If you want to read more about how to use Flexbox, [this article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is a good place to get started.

One note about Flexbox though: It doesn't work especially well on older browsers (e.g. IE 11) if that is a concern.